# how do I get the bounds of a static google map?

Tags: ruby, math, google-maps, dictionary, geolocation

I am trying to plot geo coordinates (lat/lon) on an image I retrieve via Googles static Map API. I want to do this offline directly on the image via Ruby because I want to plot about 20,000 coordinates.

However, for this task, I need to specify the corner (top left & bottom right) coordinates. 
here is the link to my map: 
http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=51.0,10.0&zoom=6&size=640x640&format=png&sensor=false

How can I get coordinates for the top left and bottom right corners of this map?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: My code for Lat/Lon -> X/Y is this for now:

```
def get_img_coords(lat, lon, w, h, lat_ul, lon_ul, lat_lr, lon_lr)
  { :x => (lon + lon_ul) * (w / (lon_lr-lon_ul)),
    :y => (lat + lat_ul) * (h / (lat_lr-lat_ul)) }
end
```

... assuming mercator projection of course.

Comment: map link problem:  "This web site needs a different Google Maps API key."

Comment: Have been looking at this one for a bit, tried a few things with public code that didn't work. I think the secret lies in [taking the tile resolution at a given zoom level](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/), moving from the known centre a known pixel distance to the edge, then computing the reverse EPSG:4326 projection to find the corner coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before. Last time I checked (which was a bit over a year ago), the Maps API encoded most of its information via Geohashing. I suggest you start by looking at [the Wikipedia page for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), and see [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060219/google-app-engine-geohashing), which appears to have a Java implementation of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The method described in this [answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511820/375432) worked perfectly for me.  Also, the code Marcelo has provided is mostly straightforward to translate from JavaScript into another language, e.g. Python.