# Specify a Google Maps Static image with borders/viewport specified by lat and lon coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to request an image from the Google Static Maps API with the borders of the map specified by a pair of latitude and longitude coordinates. I've tried centering on the center of the two coordinates, but there doesn't seem to be any parameter for doing this with the Static API. Does anyone know how to do this?

Note: this is for a desktop application, and I am *not* using the Javascript API.

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507274/how-to-get-bounds-of-a-google-static-map/12511820#12511820

Comment: if you are not using the Javascript API then you should not tag the question with Google-maps-api-3. (tag removed)

Comment: @Marcelo: sorry about the tag. I looked at your other answer, and while it is good, it is a bit in reverse of what I need. Is there perhaps a way to determine what zoom level to specify in order to get a certain magnitude of lat and lon displayed? For example, if my desired viewport is 2 deg wide and 2 deg high, what zoom level should I request, so I can then implement your answer?

Comment: there was a small error in the calculation.Sorry,  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you cannot base the request on the map's corners because 1. **zoom levels are discrete values** and 2. **the amount of latitude that a pixel represents varies with latitude**. So, to display 2 degrees you'll need a given map height near the equator and a different height, (greater), near the poles. Are you willing to display maps of different heights in order to fit always 2 degrees?

If so, you can use the MercatorProjection object from [**my other post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507274/how-to-get-bounds-of-a-google-static-map/12511820#12511820), and use the following function to calculate the necessary map size:

```
<script src="MercatorProjection.js"></script>

function getMapSize(center,zoom){
    var proj = new MercatorProjection();
    var scale = Math.pow(2,zoom);
    var centerPx = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(center);
    var SW = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()-1,center.lng()-1);
    var southzWestPx = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(SW);
    var NE = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()+1,center.lng()+1);
    var northEastPx = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(NE);

// Then you can calculate the necessary width and height of the map:
    var mapWidth = Math.round((northEastPx.x - southzWestPx.x) * scale);
    var mapHeight = Math.round((southzWestPx.y - northEastPx.y) * scale); 
}
```

With center = new google.maps.LatLng(49.141404, -121.960988) and zoom = 7 you get that you need a map of (W x H) 182 x 278 pixels in order to display 2 x 2 degrees.

Comment: @Matt, there was a small error in the calculation. Sorry, I've corrected it.